# How to display special characters in java?

Tags: java, special-characters

So, how would I display this set of characters in Java console application without using Unicode, if possible?

```
♦ ♥ ♣ ♠
```

They are created by pressing `Alt` + `(3/4/5/6)` button combination.

Comment: Why without Unicode? If so, which character set do you need?

Comment: @Thilo, I don't want to mess up my document by conversion =S I don't know if I'm right or wrong on this one.

Comment: Okay, so you just want to avoid UTF-8 for your source code files. If so, @PC. has your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to display heart `System.out.println("\u2764");`

You can find Java encoding for unicode characters [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2764/index.htm)

Comment: How is that not Unicode? OTOH, why would one use Java without Unicode?

Comment: Oh, I did not notice the **without using Unicode** section. LOL. how can you print unicode character without using unicode!!

Comment: Well, this is fine I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, one problem. It won't actually display. I get " ? " instead of that symbol as an output =/

Comment: Oh, I guess u're using Eclipse or something. Linux console will print correctly. See this link to enable Unicode characters in Eclipse console. http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/eclipse/eclipse_quickguide_display_unicode_in_console.html

Answer (score 0):

With Unicode this is a simple problem:

System.out.println("UNICODE IDENTIFIER GOES HERE");

Without Unicode? I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Ok, one problem. It won't actually display. I get " ? " instead of that symbol as an output =/